# Populating TreeListView from existing hierarchy list

Tags: c#, winforms, treenode

I have a list of objects called Items, that I want to display in a Treelistview in a hierarchy. The objects look like this:

```
public class ListItem
{
    public int ID;
    public string LabelText;
    public int ParentID;
    public bool Checked;
}
```

The list order ensures that parents are always defined first. Now I want to iterate over this list and build my hierarchy in the Treelistview. When I dectect a parent in the object I can search the already created nodes on the ListView and search for the ID, but I was wondering if it is possible to create the TreeNodes dynamically with the ID as the reference, like so (bit of pseudo code);

```
foreach (ListItem Item in Items)
{
  TreeNode {Item.ID} = new TreeNode()
  {
    Checked = Item.Checked,
    Text = Item.LabelText
  };

  if (Item.ParentID == null)
    DropDown.Nodes.Add({Item.ID});
  else
    {Item.ParentID}.SubItems.Add({Item.ID});
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid having to recursively search the existing tree every time, I'd simply store each node in a temporary `Dictionary<int,TreeNode>`. Something like this:

```
var temp = new Dictionary<int,TreeNode>();
foreach( var item in Items )
{
    var node = new TreeNode()
    {
        Checked = item.Checked,
        Text = Item.LabelText
    };
    temp.Add( item.ID, node );

    if( item.ParentID == 0 )
        DropDown.Nodes.Add( node );
    else
        // TODO: make sure node.ParentId exists in temp here
        temp[node.ParentID].SubItems.Add( node );       
}
```

Also, depending on what you need, it might also be useful to create a custom `TreeNode` class that holds a reference to the `ListItem`.

Comment: Hey Chris, never worked with Dictionaries, but is very useful for this. Also appreciate the custom TreeNode class suggestion